# Связь 3-ех моделей

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте

Есть таблицы:
**`Products`**: `id`, `title`, ...
**`Category`**: `id`, `title`, ...
**`Products_in_categories`**: `products_id`, `categories_id`

Вопрос, как наладить связь между тремя таблицами? не нашел не примеров, ничего.

Comment: что значить наладить связь? что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Думал по названию таблиц станет ясно, Я хочу на странице Каталог(Category) вывести все товары(Products) где Products_in_categories.category_id == Category.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
class Products extends CActiveRecord
{
    // ...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        // ...
             'categories' => => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category', 'Products_in_categories(products_id, categories_id)'),
        // ...
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

....

```
class Category extends CActiveRecord
{
    // ...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        // ...
             'products' => => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Products', 'Products_in_categories(categories_id, products_id)'),
        // ...
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

....

Используем:

```
$product->categories // array(Category, ...)
$category->products // array(Products, ...)
```

Comment: Для записи, возможно, придется заюзать еще кое-что. Если не получится нагуглить спрашивайте отдельным вопросом и я опишу как это делаю я.

Comment: Вы ну уточнили связь в модели ProductsInCategories

Comment: Ошибку я не допускал Модель `ProductsInCategories` не нужна.
Я привел пример с работающего проекта

Comment: `'Products_in_categories(products_id, categories_id)'),` - тут `Products_in_categories` - имя таблицы, `products_id, categories_id` - первое поле свойство текущего модуля, второе - модуль к которому тянем связь. Ошибся я в модели Category:

    'Products_in_categories(products_id, categories_id)'),

а нужно:

    'Products_in_categories(categories_id, products_id)'),

Comment: И все же, у вас ошибка в модели Category, я изменил  
self::MANY_MANY, 'Category'  
на  
self::MANY_MANY, 'Products'  
И получил именно то что нужно, а без изменений как категория обратиться к модели Товара? Спасибо, проблема решена.

Comment: Сорри. Вы правы

Answer (score 3):

Плохо искали. есть на [оф сайте](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr)

**UPDATE**
Ваш случай можно решить через связывание каждой таблицы с промежуточной.
Вот как бы намёк

> MANY_MANY: эта связь соответствует
> типу связи многие-ко-многим в БД.
> Поскольку многие СУБД не поддерживают
> непосредственно этот тип связи,
> требуется ассоциативная таблица для
> преобразования связи многие-ко-многим
> в связи один-ко-многим. В нашей схеме
> базы данных этой цели служит таблица
> tbl_post_category. В терминологии AR
> связь MANY_MANY можно описать как
> комбинацию BELONGS_TO и HAS_MANY.
> Например, Post принадлежит многим
> Category, а у Category есть много Post

**UPDATE 2**
Пример говнокодом:

```
class Product
{

    public function relations()
    {
        return array('Products_in_categories' => array(self::HAS_Ваш_тип, 'Products_in_categories', 'products_id'),
        );
    }

}

class Category
{

    public function relations()
    {
        return array('Products_in_categories' => array(self::HAS_Ваш_тип, 'Products_in_categories', 'category_id'),
        );
    }

}

class Products_in_categories
{

    public $_alias = 'Products_in_categories';

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'Products' => array(self::ваштип_связи, 'Products', '', 'on' => 'Products_in_categories.products_id = Products.products_id'),
            'Category' => array(self::ваштип_связи, 'Products', '', 'on' => 'Products_in_categories.category_id = Products.category_id'),
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: а можно пальцем тыкнуть?

Comment: @dogmar обновил ответ. Больше только кодом.

Comment: Пните меня примером : )

Comment: @dogmar ещё раз обновил ответ. в таком варианте подойдёт или вы предлагаете мне работу? :)

Comment: Что-то не завелось, поправьте пожалуйста.  
category:'products' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductsInCategories', 'categories_id'),  
ProductsInCategory: 'pinc' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', '', 'on' => 'Products_in_categories.products_id = Products.id'),   
Products: 'item' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductsInCategories', 'products_id'),  
  
Вызываю:  
$b = $this->loadModel($id);  
var_dump($b->products->pinc);  
Получаю: NULL  
Записи в БД заполнены должным образом, что не так?

Comment: @dogmar В моём коде у Products_in_categories переопределён псевдоним.

Comment: public $_alias = 'Products_in_categories'; Стоит, и с ним получаю NULL

Answer (score -1):

Связи определяются в методе public function relations() модели AR.
Почитайте:

- [Реляционная Active Record](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr)
- [Доработка модели Post](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/post.model)

К классикам трудно что-то добавить...

Comment: Я в курсе где определяются реляционные связи.